# Pivot viewer with JQuery

Tags: jquery, silverlight

I have seen the demos with Pivot viewer with Silverlight and was wondering if there are any widgets or plugins out there that do the same but with JQuery?

I like the concept of visually being able to manipulate/filter data, so are there any other plugins out there that do similar things?

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out what we've done at http://pivot.lobsterpot.com.au/html5.htm

Comment: It's open source now too. The link in my other answer to codeplex.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, it costs $30, but worth every penny as opposed to recreating the functionality yourself. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1):

Try: http://lobsterpothtml5pv.codeplex.com/